# What is the difference between GROUP and COGROUP in PIG?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I understood Group didn't work with multiple tuples and hence we had COGROUP in PIG. However, while checking today the GROUP command works for me. I am using PIG-0.12.0.
My commands and outputs are as follows.

```
grunt> grpvar = GROUP C by $2, B by $2;
grunt> cogrpvar = COGROUP C by $2, B by $2;
grunt> describe grpvar;

grpvar: {group: chararray,C: {(pid: int,pname: chararray,drug: chararray,gender: chararray,tot_amt: int)},B: {(pid: int,pname: chararray,drug: chararray,gender: chararray,tot_amt: int)}}

grunt> describe cogrpvar;

cogrpvar: {group: chararray,C: {(pid: int,pname: chararray,drug: chararray,gender: chararray,tot_amt: int)},B: {(pid: int,pname: chararray,drug: chararray,gender: chararray,tot_amt: int)}}
```

Is GROUP expected to work like this? 
What is the difference between GROUP and COGROUP them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes group is supposed to work like that !

According to the documentation ( http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#group ) :

> Note: The GROUP and COGROUP operators are identical. Both operators
>   work with one or more relations. For readability GROUP is used in
>   statements involving one relation and COGROUP is used in statements
>   involving two or more relations. You can COGROUP up to but no more
>   than 127 relations at a time.

So it is just for readability, no differences between the two.