# Difference Between Cogroup and group in apache Pig in latest verions

Tags: bigdata, apache-pig

I am not finding any difference between cogroup and group in the  latest versions(I have setups from 0.11.0 to 0.16.0) of apache pig latin.

I think for readability purpose group will be used on one relation and cogroup used on two or more relations. Other wise Group can also will be used where every cogroup used

Please let me know any one, where is special use case to use cogroup than group.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between GROUP and COGROUP in PIG?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028629/what-is-the-difference-between-group-and-cogroup-in-pig)

Comment: Note: The GROUP and COGROUP operators are identical. Both operators work with one or more relations. For readability GROUP is used in statements involving one relation and COGROUP is used in statements involving two or more relations. You can COGROUP up to but no more than 127 relations at a time.

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#group

Comment: Hi,is there any limit on using number of relation with Group operator?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment.                                                                        is there any limit on using number of relation with Group operator?. Plz let me know any use case where cogroup only will be used.